# C# ASP MVC : navigate between different controllers views from HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem navigating between different controllers views from HTML

Like for example i have two controllers (User and Transaction)

and in my HTML there is a main menu where it has all the main navigations.

so if i wanna navigate to the User list my view would be "User/List_Users"

and if i am inside the Transaction view

```
(......com/Transaction)
```

if i clicked on User List it will navigate to

```
(......com/Transaction/User/List_Users)
```

instead of going to

```
(......com/User/List_Users)
```

So i tried using The Html Action like like

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("User List","User/List_Users")</li>
```

but didn't do any good :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the overload which accepts controller name:

```
@Html.ActionLink("User List","List_Users", "User");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Link Name", "Action")</li>
```

This is your basic ActionLink. An action is the specific method in the controller (which ultimately serves up a view).

If you need to link to a different controller (you need to link to a Transaction view from a User view, for example), you can do:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Link Name", "Action", "Controller")</li>
```

Comment: @BOSS - If this answer helped you, please go ahead and accept (checkmark over to the left). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I usually use the following

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Action", "Controller", new { querystringparameter = querystringvalue }, null)
```

In your case it will be:

```
@Html.ActionLink("User List", "List_Users", "User", new { querystringparameter = querystringvalue }, null)
```